# WPF image stop repainting

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, graphics

Using WPF and MVVM I'm trying to display camera images into a `Image`.
Each frame camera got, a callback is called :

**Viewmodel**

```
public void OnNewFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Camera camera = sender as MyCamera;
    camera.ToBitmap(out _bmpImage);
    RaisePropertyChanged("BMPImage");
}
```

Each frame, I update the variable _bmpImage :

**ViewModel**

```
private Bitmap _bmpImage;
public Bitmap BMPImage
{
    get
    { return _bmpImage; }
    private set
    { _bmpImage = value; RaisePropertyChanged("BMPImage"); }
}
```

In order to convert the `Bitmap` to `BitmapImage` I use a converter :

**Converter**

```
public class ImageToSource : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Image image = value as Image;
            if (image != null)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.StreamSource = ms;
                bi.EndInit();
                return bi;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
  }
```

Finnaly bind to my view :

```
 <Image Source="{Binding Main.BMPImage, Converter={StaticResource ImageToSource}}"></Image>
```

It's work good the 15 first second, but after this delay : my `Image` becomes white. In the Converter, `image` is never `null` so camera works well. The problem is the component `Image` stop repainting.
When the `Image` is white, I can resize the window or move it and the image becomes good because `Image` is repainting.

There is something I do wrong ?
There are a way to force `Image` repainting ?
Why `Image` stop repainting ?

Thanks

**EDIT1:**

After some verification, when image becomes white, all ui freeze (so my button are not clickable until I resize or move the window)

**EDIT2**

as Dennis in the comment suggered me, I tryed to do the conversion in my ViewModel :

For that, I add a property which represent the converted image :

```
 private BitmapImage _testImage;
 public BitmapImage TestImage
 {
      get
      { return _testImage; }
      private set
      { _testImage = value; RaisePropertyChanged("TestImage"); }
 }
```

And I converted `_bmpImage` directly into `OnNewFrame`  :

```
public void OnNewFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Camera camera = sender as MyCamera;
        camera.ToBitmap(out _bmpImage);
        //RaisePropertyChanged("BMPImage");
        if (_bmpImage != null)
        {
              // Convertion
              MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
              _bmpImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
              ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
              _testImage = new BitmapImage();
              _testImage.BeginInit();
              _testImage.StreamSource = ms;
              _testImage.EndInit();
              RaisePropertyChanged("TestImage");
        }
    }
```

and bind directly the `TestImage` on my `Image`
**View**

```
<Image Source="{Binding Main.TestImage}" />
```

And with this code I've the exception :

```
Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject
```

**EDIT 3**

I have considered your remarks and it's my new code :

```
if (_bmpImage != null)
            {

                // Convertion
                Console.WriteLine("ok");
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                _bmpImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                _testImage = new BitmapImage();
                _testImage.BeginInit();
                _testImage.StreamSource = ms;
                _testImage.EndInit();

                ms.Dispose();

                System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    RaisePropertyChanged("TestImage");
                }));

            }
```

I've the same exception on `RaisePropertyChanged("TestImage");`

Juste note that Edit2 and Edit3 are a test and doesn't answer to the my original question

Sorry for the long post

Comment: What is full type name for `Bitmap`? Have you tried to perform conversion in view model, and expose `ImageSource` property from VM instead of `Bitmap`?

Comment: The full type is `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. I'll give a try

Comment: This is slowly turning into a debugging session. Posts on Stack Overflow should contain a single question (not help me debug) and not change too much over time. Perhaps you can get help using chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ and fix the question after getting down to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I use an other method to convert my Bitmap (probably faster)

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    Bitmap bmp = value as Bitmap;

    if (bmp != null)
    {
        IntPtr hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap(); 
        var drawable = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
              hBitmap,
              IntPtr.Zero,
              Int32Rect.Empty,
              BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        bmp.Dispose();
        return drawable;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll bet Your OnNewFrame method does not run on the UI thread.

In your code, change this line so it runs on the UI thread buy calling Invoke or BeginInvoke on the Dispatcher property of your window / control:

```
windowOrControlDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
{
    RaisePropertyChanged("TestImage");
}));
```

Comment: That good idea, but in my view model, I've no ui so no `windowOrControl`

Comment: But you are using WPF - and you have a window, right?  You have created  an image and some other UI elements - so there is a UI thread running.   You can even try Application.Current.Dispatcher ...

Comment: Is what I did :) check my "Edit 3"

Comment: You just need to use the same dispatcher which originally created the image control on the window,  Every UI element has the dispatcher property ... finding this is not the hardest part :-)  Do you have a mainWindow?  If so, pass a reference of the dispatcher to the ViewModel, or statically reference it, there are many ways to solve this ...

Answer (score 0):

Check the memory consumption of the application.

If the bitmaps take a lot of memory and the application does not dispose of the images and buffers

```
camera.ToBitmap(out _bmpImage);
// does this clean up the old _bmpImage?

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
// no dispose!
```

The application might be spending its time on collecting garbage instead of updating the UI.